Trying to cut (not copy) data from Sheet 2 into Sheet 1 based on cell text value
I'm brand new with a whole day of VBA coding under my belt. I've searched a host of examples cutting and pasting data from one sheet to another without success.
Herein lies my problem:
Sheet1 is "Orders"
Sheet2 is "RefundOther"
Both worksheets have headers.
"RefundOther" is full of different types of transactions in column E including "Order", "Refund", "Other-transaction", and more that show up less frequently.
I need to completely cut all rows in the sheet "RefundOther" that contain the text "Order", and paste them in the "Orders" worksheet. The range of the data can vary. Columns stay fixed A:V, but rows fluctuate daily.
Ideally I'd like to use a "last row", This code directly precedes the code I'm having issues with. It doesn't like that I'm trying to define LastRow twice. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=Vlookup(A2,NS!A:N,2,0)"
    Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=Vlookup(A2,NS!A:N,3,0)"
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=Vlookup(A2,NS!A:N,4,0)"

Worksheets("RefundOther").Copy After:=Worksheets("Orig")
Sheets("RefundOther (2)").Name = "Orders"

I've tried several examples, this is my latest attempt: 

Dim FinalRow As Long

With Sheets("RefundOther")
' Find the last row of data
     FinalRow = .Range("E").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E" & FinalRow).AutoFilter
    .Range("E" & FinalRow).AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="Order"
    .Range("E" & FinalRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Orders").Range("E").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Range("E" & FinalRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .Range("E" & FinalRow).AutoFilter
End With

This resulted in an "Application or Object-Defined Error"

Try FinalRow = .Cells( .Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row  The same will be necessary in the Copy row too. Sheets("Orders").Cells(Sheets("Orders").Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Option Explicit

Sub MoveOrders()
    
    Dim FinalRow As Long, TargetRow As Long, rng As Range
    With Sheets("RefundOther")
        ' Find the last row of data
        FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A1:V" & FinalRow)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="Order"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' remove header
            On Error GoTo 0
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No order lines found to move", vbExclamation
        Else
            With Sheets("Orders")
                TargetRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                rng.Copy .Cells(TargetRow, "A")
                MsgBox rng.Cells.Count / rng.Columns.Count & " order lines copied", vbInformation
                rng.EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End If
        
    End With

End Sub


@IngridPotter Consider the content of "RefundOther". A moved row can contain a formula that relatively refers to this row, refers to workbook-scoped names, or absolutely refers any range including sheet's name. Otherwise, you need to copy values only.

Why not [A1].CurrentRegion instead of Range("A1:V" & FinalRow)?

@rotabor Range("A1:V" & FinalRow) is what the OP seems to be familiar with.

Thank you for your help! This didn't quite accomplish what I needed. I opted instead to autofilter and delete rows not needed. It worked, and I'm almost done with my project! :)

Hello,
Thanks all for the suggestions, Ultimately I had to use an .Autofilter function, and learn the hard way that I can only use 2 criteria at a time. Luckily I only have 3 criteria.
So I ran a .Autofilter using the xlOR operator, deleted visible rows, turned off autofilter for the orders sheet, and again for the Refund/Other sheet.
I'm close to completely solving this complex project, just pressure testing with each payment now. Thanks for everyone's help again, it's been a lot of fun learning as I go!

A moved row can contain a formula that relatively refers to this row, refers to workbook-scoped names, or absolutely refers (including sheet's name) any range. Considering the content of "RefundOther", you may need to copy values only:
Option Explicit

Sub MoveOrdersValuesOnly()
  Dim o As Worksheet, r As Worksheet, a, arradr$, condadr$
  Set o = Sheets("Orders"): Set r = Sheets("RefundOther")
  With r.[A1].CurrentRegion
    arradr = r.Name & "!" & .Address()
    condadr = r.Name & "!" & .Columns(5).Address()
    a = Application.Evaluate("FILTER(" & arradr & "," & condadr & "=""Order"")")
    If IsArray(a) Then
      o.Cells(o.[A1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2)) = a
      a = Application.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,MAP(FILTER(SEQUENCE(" & .Rows.Count & ")," & condadr & "=""Order""),LAMBDA(r,r&"":""&r)))")
      r.Range(a).Delete
    End If
  End With
End Sub


A more simple approach would be to cycle through the rows of sheet 'RefundOther' via 'for...next' starting with last row of this sheet (step -1 because you're going to delete rows), copy each cell value from A to V (column 1…22) via another 'for...next' to the designated target sheet (where you looked up its last row beforehand) and delete the source row then.
I'd like to apologize that I don't provide any code, but I'm sitting at a patients tablet in a hospital, bored to death, struggeling with the Autocorrection.
